# Toggling a drawer from header icon using react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am new to react-native and react-navigation.
Required Screen: A home page with a header (Thumbnail + title) , two tabs and a drawer that toggles onPress of the thumbnail.

### Please check my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform,  StyleSheet,  Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {Icon, Button} from 'native-base';
const util = require('util');
import { TabNavigator, StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
import FirstScreen from './tabs/FirstScreen';
import SecondScreen from './tabs/SecondScreen';
import Profile from './Profile';
import SearchScreen from './tabs/SearchScreen';

const DrawerScreens = DrawerNavigator({
    Profile: {screen: Profile}
},{
    drawerPosition: 'left',
    drawerWidth: 150
});

// A drawer navigator

 const TabScreens= TabNavigator({
    First: {screen: FirstScreen},
    Second: {screen: SecondScreen}
  }); 

//   Started with a tab navigator to register two tabs

  const MenuButton =({navigation})=>{
   return(
        <View>        
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>(navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle'))}>
            <Icon name="person" size= {20}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>)};

export const StackScreens= StackNavigator({
    Draw: {screen: DrawerScreens},
    // Drawer navigator as a screen
    Display: {screen: TabScreens, 
        // Making the tabnavigator as a screen
        navigationOptions: ({navigation})=>({
        title: 'Welcome',
        headerLeft: <MenuButton navigation={navigation} />
      })
    },

},{
    initialRouteName: 'Display'
});
```

---

On pressing of the thumbnail the TabScreens navigates to the DrawerScreens (since that is how i coded). I want to make it toggle. Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some general ideas on [how to structure your navigator properly.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47629588/9049053)

What `react-navigation` version are you using?

Try changing your `MenuButton` helper method to this and see if it helps

```
if (navigation.state.index === 0) {
    navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')
  } else {
    navigation.navigate('DrawerClose')
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help much. The drawer was still behaving as a screen. Any other suggestions, please.